# Переход к следующей задаче, при выполнении условия

Tags: c#

Программа вызывает через командную строку декриптор, после чего вызывается следующая программа приводящая декомпилированный файл в текстовый вид, после чего текстовый файл редактируется и в обратном порядке производятся операции ("подготовка к компиляции" -> компиляция).
Проблема в том что, декомпиляция и привод к текстовому виду (а также и обратные операции) не нормированны по времени, в некоторых файлах декомпилируется 20000 строк, в другом 65000 строк. Пытался поставить делей между операциями по закрытию командной строки, но не выходит. Пробовал через Thread,Task.Delay и др варианты предложенные в интернете. Возможно я что-то делаю не так?
Вот код класса запускающего все процессы:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using l2patcher.Modules.SkillGrpEdit;
using l2patcher.Engine.EncDec;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace l2patcher.Engine.Editing
{
    class EditBegin
    {
        public void Prepare(string skillsBTD,string skillsDA, string skillsDI, bool skillsTalis, bool skillsLS, bool skillsCocktail)
        {

            Decrypt.l2encdec();
            while (CheckProcess())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("decyrpted!");

            DisAsm.l2disasm();
            while (CheckProcess())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("disasm'ed!");

            Editor.BuffToDebuff(skillsBTD);
            while (CheckState() == false)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("added to debuff!");

            Editor.DeleteAnimation(skillsDA);
            while (CheckState() == false)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("deleted animation!");

            Editor.ChangeIcons(skillsDI);
            while (CheckState() == false)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("deleted icons!");

            Asm.l2asm();
            while (CheckProcess())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("asm'ed!");

            Encrypt.l2encdec();
            while (CheckProcess())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("encyrpted!");

            MessageBox.Show("OK");
        }

        bool CheckProcess()
        {
            Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd.exe");
            if (pname.Length != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(pname.Length));
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        bool CheckState()
        {
            if (Modules.SkillGrpEdit.Editor.State)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var process = new Process() {StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "arguments")}; process.WaitForExit();` ?

Comment: @tym32167 благодарю, работает. Главное не забыть запустить)

Comment: ну да, писал по памяти, подзабыл детали, хорошо, что сами увидели про запуск :)